# Virtual Address Space limits in Windows NT: arbitrary for Itanium?

Tags: windows, 64-bit, memory-limit, intel-itanium

[This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#memory_limits) lists the virtual address space limits for current versions of Windows.

I notice that for 32 bit systems the address space is divided into 2 GB user and 2 GB kernel, which makes sense. Likewise on amd64 systems the (presumably 44 bit) address space is divided into 8 TB user space and 8 TB kernel space.

But ia64 has 7 TB user space. Is this an arbitrary limit or is it because the system uses 9 TB for the kernel space or why is this?

Comment: I'm sure the nerds in SO or SF know the answer to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mark Russinovich explains it here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2008/11/17/3155406.aspx

It turns out that the difference is centered in a Windows specific feature. For IA64, the top 1TB of the 8TB memory-space is reserved for wow64 mappings. Wow64 is the feature that allows running 32-bit code on a 64-bit system. The reason that X64-64 (a.k.a. amd64) doesn't have it, is that it is ISA-compatable so just need the right libraries to run.